# Change email view path for password reset on Laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel, passwords

Using Laravel 5, I need 2 different views for password reset email. The default path to the email view is **emails.password**. But upon some conditions, I want to send **emails.password_alternative**.

How can I do this? (with PasswordBroker from Laravel)

This is my current code:

```
public function __construct(Guard $auth, PasswordBroker $passwords)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
    $this->passwords = $passwords;
}

public function sendReset(PasswordResetRequest $request)
{
    //HERE : If something, use another email view instead of the default one from the config file
    $response = $this->passwords->sendResetLink($request->only('email'), function($m)
    {
        $m->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`PasswordBroker`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Contracts/Auth/PasswordBroker.html) and based on the [`Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/fcb4768e02006635bb78d2f6626f5aaa89430e98/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php) class, the `$emailView` is a protected variable, so you can't change the value once the class is instantiated.

However, you have a couple of solutions:

1. You can create your own class that extends PasswordBroker and use that.

   ```
   class MyPasswordBroker extends PasswordBroker {
       public function setEmailView($view) {
           $this->emailView = $view;
       }
   }

   // (...)

   public function __construct(Guard $auth, MyPasswordBroker $passwords)
   {
       $this->auth = $auth;
       $this->passwords = $passwords;
   }

   public function sendReset(PasswordResetRequest $request)
   {
       if ($someConditionHere) {
           $this->passwords->setEmailView('emails.password_alternative');
       }
       $response = $this->passwords->sendResetLink($request->only('email'), function($m)
       {
           $m->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
       });
   }
   ```
2. You could create the PasswordBroker within your method, without using Dependency Injection.

   ```
   public function sendReset(PasswordResetRequest $request)
   {
       $emailView = 'emails.password';

       if ($someConditionHere) {
           $emailView = 'emails.password_alternative';
       }

       $passwords = new PasswordBroker(
           App::make('TokenRepositoryInterface'),
           App::make('UserProvider'),
           App::make('MailerContract'),
           $emailView
       );

       $response = $passwords->sendResetLink($request->only('email'), function($m)
       {
           $m->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
       });
   }
   ```

   This is an uglier solution and if you have automated tests this will be a pain to work with.

*Disclaimer*: I've not tested any of this code.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention I am using Laravel PasswordBroker

Comment: Is there a reason why the variable is protected with no setter? Or did Laravel set it to protected because they didn't think of a case where people would like to change it?

Comment: I'm guessing they didn't thought about that. The best way to find out is to create a GitHub Issue and discuss that with Laravel's main developers.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone interested in Laravel 5.2 you can set a custom html and text email view for password reset by adding

```
config(['auth.passwords.users.email' => ['auth.emails.password.html', 'auth.emails.password.text']]);
```

to the PasswordController.php in the constructor before the middleware call.

This overrides the app/config/auth.php setup for the PasswordBroker.

Blade Template for the password reset email is then located at:

> yourprojectname/resources/views/auth/emails/password/html.blade.php
>   yourprojectname/resources/views/auth/emails/password/text.blade.php

Took me long enough.

Credits: 
http://ericlbarnes.com/2015/10/14/how-to-send-both-html-and-plain-text-password-reset-emails-in-laravel-5-1/
http://academe.co.uk/2014/01/laravel-multipart-registration-and-reminder-emails/